# Netbooks/Notebooks without cam?

Tags: windows, laptop, netbook, camera

Where I work, I'm not allowed to have cameras or *any* devices with cameras, so I wonder if there're any netbooks (preferably) or notebooks available without cameras? I searched a lot but couldn't find any.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Rather weird rule - why not just uninstall drivers ? Or sever the internet connection ? Or put 5cm of duck tape against it. I understand why such a rule would exist, but nowadays, when everything but toasters are equipped with cameras, it's just silly.

Answer (score 1):

Most main hardware manufacturers have Notebooks without camera. I bought some HP probooks and I had an option to have or not camera in them. Dell also should have this option.

Comment: We have had both 2510p ultraportables and 6930p Elitebooks without cameras from HP. Unfortunately most netbooks do have cameras.

Comment: Yes, but those are expensive. Is there something available around $500?